# Including a navigational property in a .Where()?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a couple of tables with a parent-child relationship. E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE parent
(
    parentid VARCHAR(32),
    name VARCHAR(128),
    CONSTRAINT PK_parent PRIMARY KEY (parentid)
);

CREATE TABLE child
(
    parentid VARCHAR(32),
    childid VARCHAR(32),
    name VARCHAR(128),
    age INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT PK_child PRIMARY KEY (parentid, childid),
    CONSTRAINT FK_child_parent FOREIGN KEY (parentid)
    REFERENCES parent (parentid)
);
```

I need to find parent records where some condition on the child is true.  In SQL, this is simple:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM parent AS p
JOIN child AS c
ON c.parentid = p.parentid
WHERE c.age = 10
;
```

But how do I do this in Entity Framework?

I have a navigational property defined, so that the parent class has a collection of children, so I'd expect to be able to include a .Where(p=>p.child.age == 10), but that doesn't work.

What does?

Comment: Are you using linq to entities? Can you post your query that "doesnt work" and its error?

Comment: I'm using EF 6.1.  As for "doesn't work", it's conceptually nonsensical, as there isn't one child, so comparing to its value makes no sense. What I'd need is .Where(p => p.children.Contains(c => c.age == 10)), but that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your navigation property is a collection, you have to use `Any`:

```
.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Age == 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the foriegn key is defined, EF will automatically add a property for it:

```
from p in Parent
where p.Children.Any(c=> c.Age == 10)
select p;
```

or

```
from c in child
where c.Age == 10
select c.Parent;
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as `Where(p => p.child.age == 10)`, which OP tried and doesn't work.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - realized it & fixed it.

Comment: The FK goes the other way.  There isn't a p.Child, there's a p.childs.

Comment: @JeffDege A Foreign key goes both ways. It should create both properties: p.childs and c.parent

Comment: Yes, but As this answer was originally formulated, it was chasing the FK relationship in the wrong direction. It assumed that there was one child to many parents. It's since been fixed.